# Purple screen delay at Ubuntu 11.04 boot

Tags: 11.04

I've got Windows 7 & Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my PC.
When I install Ubuntu, it came with GRUB.

On GRUB, when I select "Ubuntu" on boot menu, I've got a purple screen during 16 seconds, and passed 16 seconds it shows the boot screen and loads the desktop.

Actually, I've got BURG installed on my PC but now, when I try to boot Ubuntu, it shows a black screen with a blinking cursor durin 16 seconds.

Can I remove that delay?

And sorry for my bad english, I'm from Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntero. Hello, ubuntero. You mean the screen is left in purple after giving Ubuntu in GRUB?

That is booting Ubuntu. Actually, you should see the logo and a moving dot , but often not. I send you a link to a post I found, and now I will try it on my PC:

http://lamaquinadiferencial.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/como-arreglar-el-logo-de-arranque-de-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/

Greetings from Spain;)

P.S if a command is called "`sudo aptitude`", change it to "`sudo apt-get`".

---

Hola, ubuntuero. ¿Quieres decir que la pantalla se te queda en morado después de dar a Ubuntu en GRUB?

Eso es el arranque de Ubuntu. En realidad, debería aparecer el logo y unos "ciculitos" de carga, pero muchas veces no es así. Te envío un enlace a un post que encontré, y que ahora voy a probar con mi PC:

http://lamaquinadiferencial.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/como-arreglar-el-logo-de-arranque-de-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/

Saludos desde España ;)

Comment: and for us who doesn't understand spanish? (or whatever this is...)

Comment: Ummm. Muchas gracias espectalll123 por tu rapidez en la respuesta pero no, ese no es mi problema. Antes de que se muestre la pantalla de inicio (con el logo de ubuntu) se queda una pantalla morada por unos 10 segundos y luego se ve el logo de ubuntu y arranca el sistema. ._."

Comment: Entonces, ¿de qué se trata? No conozco BURG, por ejemplo. Déjame ver...

Vale, revisado. Pues no sé de que se trata... ¿puede ser que BURG falle?

Comment: Bueno. En realidad esto me sucedía antes con GRUB, ahora, con BURG me pasa lo mismo pero en vez de la pantalla morada sale uan pantalla negra con un "_" parpadeando durante unos 10 segundos. Luego arranca sin problemas. Ya intenté con nomodeset, acpi=off y con mil cosas pero no hay suerte :|

Comment: No creo que sea burg. Me parece que es un problema de drivers. Por si es de utilidad tengo el Acer Aspire 5736Z :P

Comment: Vale, tal vez BURG arranque Ubuntu de una manera diferente a GRUB solo, y entonces no se ponga el normal. En ese caso, tendrías que revisar el comando que usa BURG para arrancar.

Comment: No creo que sea de drivers, sinceramente...

Comment: Si te refieres a la línea de comandos está usando "quiet splash nohz=off" ._. El "nohz=off" se lo añadí yo para ver si funcionaba pero no hay suerte

Comment: Vale, revisaré por Internet posibles soluciones... mientras espero a la mía del sonido :P

Comment: OK, voy a revisarla por si puedo ayudarte en algo. Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Mírate esto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options

Comment: OK, gracias. Seguro que es algo del ACPI ;)

Comment: Ńada, no hubo suerte ):

Comment: Tal vez BURG no funcione en tu ordenador, siempre existe la posibilidad.